# Nested Ajax Calls Promises to Rest Service

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

Suppose I have a REST api like this:

(I can ask for a list of Contracts)

Request: GET www.domain.com/contracts/list

Response:

```
[{"contractId": 1, "contractDate":"2017-05-26", "partnerId": 1},
{"contractId": 2, "contractDate":"2017-05-26", "partnerId": 2},
{"contractId": 3, "contractDate":"2017-05-26", "partnerId": 1}, {more JSON Objects ...}]
```

(I can ask for partners {id} is a parameter)

Request: GET www.domain.com/partners/{id}

Response: `{"partenerId": 1, "name":"StackOverflow", "bankAccountsId":[{"bankAccountId": 7}, {"bankAccountId": 33}]}`

(I can ask for BankAccounts)

Request: GET www.domain.com/bankaccounts/{id}

Response: `{"bankAccountId":7, "iban":"124531YDS51625316126", "bankId": 25}`

(I can ask for Banks)

Request: GET www.domain.com/banks/{id}

Response: `{"bankId":25, "name":"CityBank"}`

What whould be the right way to show a list from Javascript like this:

> Contract Id : 1
>
> Contract Date: 26.05.2017
>
> Partner Name: Stackoverflow
>
> Bank Accounts:
>
> 124531YDS51625316126 CityBank
>
> 128737ING01231623812 ING
>
> .....more....

At this moment I use a combination of Ajax Calls(Promises) and Closures to render the list I will show you how but I don't feel its the right way and seems to me very complicated (I use Jquery for the Axaj calls and don't use ES6 features):

```
function render() {
    var output = document.createDocumentFragment();
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/contacts/list'
    }).done(function(contracts){
        for (var i=0, l=contracts.length; i<l; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = contracts[i].contractId;
            output.appendChild(div);
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = contracts[i].contractDate;
            output.appendChild(div);
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            output.appendChild(div);
            (function (place, _partenerId) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://www.example.com/partners/',
                    data: {partenerId:_partenerId}
                }).done(function(partner){
                     place.innerHTML = partner.name;
                     for (var j=0; j<partener.bankAccountsId.length; j++) {
                         (function(place, _bankAccountId) {
                             jQuery.ajax({
                                 method: 'GET',
                                 url: 'https://www.example.com/bankaccounts/',
                                 data: {bankAccountId:_bankAccountId}
                             }).done(function (bankAccount) {
                                 var div = document.createElement('div');
                                 div.innerHTML = bankAccount.iban;
                                 place.insertAfter(div);
                                 /* I Still have to ask for the Bank name but I stop my example here*/
                             });
                          )(place, partener.bankAccountsId[j]);
                     }
                });     
            })(div, contracts[i].partenerId);
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

The code won't work as it its and its just to see the principle I use. I hope there are better solutions to consume an Rest API in Javascript where you have to ask for nested structures.

Comment: Use Promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: jQuery.axaj is a promise but not a A+ one what do you mean by use Promise?